# Deleting playlist item with youtube api

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have tried to delete a playlist item with the following to methods:

```
function deleteVideoFromPlaylist($vid, $youtube) {
  $youtube->playlistItems->delete($vid);
}

function playlistItemsDelete($youtube, $id, $params) {
    $params = array_filter($params);
    $response = $youtube->playlistItems->delete(
        $id,
        $params
    );
    print_r($response);
}
```

and both of them are saying playlistItemsNotAccessible/Forbidden:

```
Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 
'{\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": 
"youtube.playlistItem",\n    "reason": "playlistItemsNotAccessible",\n 
 "message": "Forbidden",\n    "locationType": "parameter",\n    
"location": "id"\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 403,\n  "message":
 "Forbidden"\n }\n}\n' in /var/www/html/nextcloud_yt_integration/google-
api-php-client-2.2.0/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/nextcloud_yt_integration/google-api-php-client-2.2.0/src/Google/Http/REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), NULL)\n#1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), NULL)\n#2 /var/www/html/nextcloud_yt_integration/google-api-php-client-2.2.0/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(176): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#3 /var/www/html/nextcloud_yt_integration/google-api-php-client-2.2.0/src/Google/Http/REST.php(58): Google_Task_Runner->run()\n#4 /va in /var/www
/html/nextcloud_yt_integration/google-api-php-client-2.2.0/src/Google
/Http/REST.php on line 118
```

As well as both these methods doing this the API explorer also says that I do not have permission to do it - with all scopes authorised

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/delete#errors), `playlistItemsNotAccessible` error means that the request is not properly authorized to delete the specified playlist item. If you haven't done so, please see this [page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) to know more about the OAuth 2.0 concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm just an idiot and was authorizing the wrong channel..